# Why does PSI API put values of originLoadingExperience in loadingExperience, in case CRuX does not have sufficient real-world speed data for the page?

Tags: pagespeed-insights, chrome-ux-report

In case the Chrome User Experience Report does not have sufficient real-world speed data for the *page*, the response of the PSI API (v5) does contain values for all properties of `loadingExperience` in the response. These values are exactly the same as the values for `originLoadingExperience`.
The problem with this is that from the API response you can't know if the data in `loadingExperience` is valid or the duplicate of `originLoadingExperience`.
Sure, it's possible to compare all those values and if all match exactly it is kinda safe to conclude it's a case of duplication, but this is not bullet-proof and requires extra code.

Is there a way to reliably know from the API response if CRuX did not have sufficient data for the page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I've seen this too and I consider it a bug in the PSI API. I've already flagged it with the PSI team suggesting that they include an error message in the `loadingExperience` field to clarify that it doesn't have sufficient data for the page.